# Getting the norm of a complex expression

Tags: complex

I'm trying to get the norm of a complex function with symbolic notation. But really I'm very inexperienced at this.

```
FullSimplify[Abs[ExpToTrig[Exp[I*x*t]]], Assumptions -> {t ∈ Reals, x ∈ Reals}]
```

With this code, I got 1. That's right!

So, now I'm trying to use this in the following problem:
$\frac{e^{it(w_{21}+w)}-1}{w+w_{21}}+\frac{e^{it(w_{21}-w)}-1}{w_{21}-w}$

```
F[w_, t_] = Exp[I*w*t];
FullSimplify[
  Abs[
    ExpToTrig[
      (F[w + Subscript[w, 21], t] - 1)/(w + Subscript[w, 21]) + 
      (F[Subscript[w, 21] - w, t] - 1)/(Subscript[w, 21] - w)]],
  Assumptions -> {t ∈ Reals,Subscript[w, 21] ∈ Reals, w ∈ Reals}]
```

But in this case the function `Abs` doesn't work. Can you tell me where I made my mistakes?

Comment: How do you expect *Mathematica* to do anything when it doesn't know anything about the function `F[]`?

Comment: I had forgotten to put that part.

Comment: Your first expression can be simplified to `Abs[Exp[I*x*t]] // ComplexExpand` which as expected evaluates to `1`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html)

```
F[w_, t_] = Exp[I*w*t];

expr = Abs[(F[w + Subscript[w, 21], t] - 1)/(w + 
       Subscript[w, 21]) + (F[Subscript[w, 21] - w, t] - 
       1)/(Subscript[w, 21] - w)] // ComplexExpand
```

[image]

An alternate representation is

```
expr // ExpandAll // Simplify
```

[image]